# Prevent other windows from overlapping my form?

Tags: c#

I have a form that is on the 2nd monitor and full-screen. I want to prevent all other windows from accidently being  moved into the second screen and over lapping my form.

I also need to make sure that if a window gets moved to the other window and I use topmost, I don't want the other window to get lost.

I want to make the 2nd monitor( or my app ) un-overlappable. Not necessarily make it the topmost app.

This is a c# form.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: yes, topmost will do it.  but as always, the question will be "why is your form more important than everything else?"  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`Form.TopMost` property:

> A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other (non-topmost)
>   forms even if it is not the active or foreground form. Topmost forms
>   are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the
>   windows on the desktop. You can use this property to create a form
>   that is always displayed in your application, such as a Find and
>   Replace tool window.